# Can't get multi day events to display properly over multiple months

Tags: solspace-calendar

I would like to display Solspace calendar dates in a list so the dates display as follows:

- One day event - May 31
- Multi day event - May 30-31
- Multi day event with range in 2 months - May 31-Jun 1

I've been unable to get both multi day options to work using the following conditional. For multi day events over 2 months, it still displays May 31-1.

My code is:

```
{if event_multi_day AND {event_start_date format="%M"} == {event_end_date format="%M"}}
{event_start_date format="%M %j"}-{event_end_date format="%j"}
{if:elseif {event_start_date format="%M"} != {event_end_date format="%M"}}
{event_start_date format="%M %j"}-{event_end_date format="%M %j"}
{if:else}
{event_start_date format="%M %j"}
{/if}
```

To narrow down the issue further, if I have an event that occurs May 31 to June 1, and want it to display May 31-Jun 1, I get no result if I use the following:

```
{if {event_start_date format="%M"} != {event_end_date format="%M"}}
{event_start_date format="%M %j"}-{event_end_date format="%M %j"}{/if}
```

Comment: You are comparing `event_multi_day` with `{event_start_date format="%M"}`. Should that not both be between curly brackets? So `{if {event_multi_day} AND {event_start_date format="%M"}`

Comment: I'm not sure the curly brackets I'm using are correct, but if I add them around 'event_multi_day', I get a parse error. The problem seems to be that != is being ignored in the 3rd line.

Comment: Just some other thoughts. Try to put the variable between quotes `{if "{var1}" != "{var2}"}` and maybe test `event_multi_day` against `true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer to my own question. I was using the wrong placement and combination of " and '. What works for me is as follows:

```
{if event_multi_day AND "{event_start_date format='%M'}" == "{event_end_date format='%M'}"}
{event_start_date format="%M %j"}-{event_end_date format="%j"}
{if:elseif "{event_start_date format='%M'}" != "{event_end_date format='%M'}"}
{event_start_date format="%M %j"}-{event_end_date format="%M %j"}
{if:else}
{event_start_date format="%M %j"}
{/if}
```

Thanks to those who responded.